# parse json file from a url

Tags: php, curl

I looked up various posts here on SO regarding parsing a JSON file from a URL. I have been trying to achieve the same using these solutions but it is not working for me. As of now I am using the below simple code to parse a JSON file from a URL on a internal server:-

```
<?php

function get_content($URL){
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
      }


echo get_content('http://someurl/rohan_test/files/cob_apollo.json');
?>
```

Can someone please suggest as to what am I missing over here as far as parsing the URL is concerned...All i am getting is the "Error code:500 - internal server error".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open the provided url in a browser?

Comment: Your code seems perfectly fine. Are you sure this is the whole thing?

Comment: Do you have PHP CURL extension enabled? Try with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I tried with file_get_contents() but was getting bool(false). I just enabled the extension for php and it worked for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

try `json_decode()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

and is CURL really needed? `file_get_contents()` should be good enough

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://someurl/rohan_test/files/cob_apollo.json');
$json = json_decode($json_string);
echo "<pre>".print_r($json, true)."</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// First get the data and put into phpObject

$json = file_get_contents('http://someurl/files/file.json');
$phpObject =  json_decode($json,true);

// Grab data from the phpObject

echo  $phpObject["query"]["results"][1]["result"];

?>
```